# How can I modificated a Nodo C?

Tags: c, algorithm, list, nodes

I have this function and I have a problem with the while loop

```
_nodoMaterias *modificarMateria(char materia[], _nodoMaterias *apuntador)
{
    printf("\nENTRO");
    if (!listaVacia(apuntador))
    {
        printf("\nENTRO1");
        _nodoMaterias *apuntadorAuxiliar;

        apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntador;

        while (apuntadorAuxiliar != NULL && strcmp(apuntadorAuxiliar->nombre, materia) != 0)
        {
            printf("\nENTRO2");
            if (apuntadorAuxiliar != NULL && strcmp(apuntadorAuxiliar->nombre, materia) != 0)
            {
                char nombre[30];
                char profesor[30];
                char tipoDeMateria[20];
                char horasSemanales[10];

                printf("\nINGRESE LOS NUEVOS DATOS DE LA MATERIA");
                printf("NOMBRE: ");
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf("%s",nombre);
                printf("PROFESOR: ");
                fflush(stdin);  
                scanf("%s",profesor);
                printf("TIPO DE MATERIA: ");
                fflush(stdin);  
                scanf("%s",tipoDeMateria);
                printf("HORAS SEMANALES:  ");
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf("%s",horasSemanales);
                fflush(stdin);

                strcpy(apuntadorAuxiliar->nombre, nombre);
                strcpy(apuntadorAuxiliar->profesor, profesor);
                strcpy(apuntadorAuxiliar->tipoDeMateria, tipoDeMateria);
                strcpy(apuntadorAuxiliar->horasSemanales, horasSemanales);
                apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente = NULL;
            }

            apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente;
        }

    }

    return apuntador;
}
```

When I compile it goes perfect but when I use it, never enter in the while loop but I don't know why.

But it prints "ENTRO" and "ENTRO1".

How can I solve this?

Comment: It's hard to say exactly but the only way into the while loop is if apuntador->material contains a value and if it is different to materia.  So how do you know what they hold?  Change `printf("\nENTRO1");` to `printf("\nENTRO1: %s, %s",apuntador?apuntador->nombre:"null",materia);` and tell us what is printed.

Comment: It prints "ENTRO1: CALCULO, CALCULO"

Comment: Ok, like I said, it only enters the while loop if the strings are different.  And they aren't different so it doesn't enter the while loop.  If you can describe what you want it to do maybe we can figure out how to make it do it.

Comment: I want to modify the node in my list, for example I have my list with two nodes one is calculus and the other is physics, then i ask to the user which node you want to modify? when the user writes which node want to modify, my code must be able of modify this node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to modify the node if the user input name matches the node's name, in that case, you need to change the condition of `strcmp` to `==`, as it returns zero when the two string matches. Also the check should be put in the inner `if`, not the outer `while`:

```
while (apuntadorAuxiliar != NULL) {
    if (strcmp(apuntadorAuxiliar->nombre, materia) == 0) {
        // modifying the node
    }
}
```